# Trigger in SQL Server involving an if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a trigger for my order processing application for which I want to insert the customer details in a table called `new_cust` if he has placed an order for the first time else do nothing.

This is what I have come up with but it gives an error saying:

> The multi-part identifier "inserted.cust_no" could not be bound.

My code:

```
create trigger new_insert
on customer
after insert 
as 
begin
    select * 
    from customer 
    where not exists (select * from new_cust 
                      where c_no = inserted.cust_no);
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `inserted` has no context, you haven't included it in your `FROM`. This, however, feels like something you should be handling in the SP that is doing the `INSERT`, rather than in a `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
create trigger new_insert
on customer
after insert as
begin
    inset into new_cust ( . . . ) -- list columns here
        select . . .              -- list columns here
        from inserted i
        where not exists (select 1 from new_cust nc where nc.c_no = i.cust_no)
end;
```

That said, it is baffling to me why duplicate customers would be allowed into a table called `customer`.  That sounds like a data modeling problem.  Also, the column `cust_no` should have a consistent name across the tables.